# how to load next string when i erase particle text?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl, particles

I am new to vanilla js and webgl content. I created a particle text which get distorted on mouse hover. and whose particles are connected   with each other with a line. the code is as follows.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
//console.log(dpr);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let particleArray = [];
let adjustX = 10;
let adjustY = 0;
//handle mouse
const mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  radius: 30,
};
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  mouse.x = event.x;
  mouse.y = event.y;
  //console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y);
});


ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "35px verdana";
ctx.fillText("aman ", 0, 30);

const textCoordinates = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x + Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    this.y = y + Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    this.size = 1;
    this.baseX = this.x;
    this.baseY = this.y;
    this.density = Math.random() * 10 + 50;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  //distance between mouse and particle
  update() {
    let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
    let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    let forceDirectionX = dx / distance;
    let forceDirectionY = dy / distance;
    let maxDistance = mouse.radius;
    let force = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance;
    let directionX = forceDirectionX * force * this.density;
    let directionY = forceDirectionY * force * this.density;

    if (distance < mouse.radius) {
      this.x -= directionX;
      this.y -= directionY;
    } else {
      if (this.x !== this.baseX) {
        let dx = this.x - this.baseX;
        this.x += dx / 10;
      }
      if (this.y !== this.baseY) {
        let dy = this.y - this.baseY;
        this.y += dy / 10;
      }
    }
  }
}

//console.log(textCoordinates);
function init() {
  particleArray = [];
  for (let y = 0, y2 = textCoordinates.height; y < y2; y++) {
    for (let x = 0, x2 = textCoordinates.width; x < x2; x++) {
      if (
        textCoordinates.data[y * 4 * textCoordinates.width + x * 4 + 3] > 128
      ) {
        let positionX = x + adjustX;
        let positionY = y + adjustY;
        particleArray.push(new Particle(positionX * 4, positionY * 4));
      }
    }
  }
}
init();
//console.log(particleArray);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++) {
    particleArray[i].draw();
    particleArray[i].update();
  }
  connect();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
function connect() {
  let opacityValue = 1;
  for (let a = 0; a < particleArray.length; a++) {
    for (let b = a; b < particleArray.length; b++) {
      let dx = particleArray[a].x - particleArray[b].x;
      let dy = particleArray[a].y - particleArray[b].y;
      let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      if (distance < 14) {
        opacityValue = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(200,150,160," + opacityValue + ")";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(particleArray[a].x, particleArray[a].y);
        ctx.lineTo(particleArray[b].x, particleArray[b].y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now what I want to do is that, when I erase this particle text, next text must appear. just like on this website https://animal.cc/ .
can anyone please help me in this :))

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't three.js related)
When you determine "this particle text" has been erased, you can do this in animate():

```
ctx.fillText("NEW ", 0, 30);
textCoordinates = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
init();
```

EDIT: code for comment (below)

```
  for (let y = 0, y2 = textCoordinates.height; y < y2; y++) {
    for (let x = 0, x2 = textCoordinates.width; x < x2; x++) {
```

Comment: hi dcromley , thanks for answering my question. actually I tried to determine whether the text has been erased or not but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I guess that you will have to do the loop that you used before (see edited answer for code) and see if all (or most) of the pixels are erased.